# Prove that $\sigma^2_{X+Y}=\sigma_X^2+\sigma_Y^2$ without independence

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory

Given that:

$\mu_X = \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty xf(x)dx$, and

$\sigma_X^2=\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty(x-\mu_X)^2f(x)dx$.

Let $X$ and $Y$ be random variables with pdf's $f_X$ and $f_Y$. Prove that $\sigma^2_{X+Y}=\sigma_X^2+\sigma_Y^2$.

So my proof begins:

$\sigma_{X+Y}^2 = \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty ((x+y)-\mu_{X+Y})^2f_{XY}(x,y)\,dx\,dy =\dots$ and I get to here.

$=\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty (x-\mu_X)^2f_X(x)\,dx+\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty (y-\mu_Y)^2 f_Y(y)\,dy+\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty2(x-\mu_X)(y-\mu_Y)f_{XY}(x,y)\,dx\,dy$.

This is almost exactly what I want as long as I can show that $\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty2(x-\mu_X)(y-\mu_Y)f_{XY}(x,y)\,dx\,dy = 0$. This is where I am having trouble.

$\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty2(x-\mu_X)(y-\mu_Y)f_{XY}(x,y)\,dx\,dy = $

$2\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty (y-\mu_Y) \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty(x-\mu_X)f_{XY}(x,y)\,dx\,dy = $

$2\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty (y-\mu_Y)\left[ \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty xf_{XY}(x,y)\,dx-\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \mu_Xf_{XY}(x,y)\,dx\right]\,dy $

This is where I am stuck, and I am not sure if I took it the right direction. Can anyone provide insight on how to proceed? Thank you.

Comment: This is the part where you use $f_{XY}(x,y) = f_X(x)f_Y(y)$ as $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Comment: It looks like you split $f_{XY}(x,y)$ into $f_X(x)$ and $f_Y(y)$, but doesn't this use independence? Also, can you use that when $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then their correlation is $0$?

Comment: I'm not clear when you say "without using independence".

Comment: I think the title is misleading, considering the question specifically says we should assume independence (otherwise it's not true in general).

Comment: You're absolutely right I apologize. This is meant to be without independence. I am just in the habit of typing independent. I made an edit.

Comment: If there is no independence then in general the statement is not true. E.g. take $X=Y$ then $\sigma_{X+Y}^2=\sigma_{2X}^2=4\sigma_{X}^2$

Comment: Maybe it was meant to be added to the assignment but was not.